# Incompatible Types String and Char

Tags: java

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. I think the code in general is okay although I'm sure there is a shorter way then using all the else ifs. The problem is it says incompatible types and I really am just lost on how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MissionImpossible
{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        String lineOne,  R2D2 = "";

       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Please enter a word so I can see how many vowels it has.");

       int count = 0;

       lineOne = in.nextLine();

       int word = lineOne.length();

       for (int i = word -1; i>= 0; i--) 
        {
            R2D2= lineOne.charAt(i);

            if (R2D2== 'a'|| R2D2=='A')
            count++;
            else if (R2D2=='e'||R2D2=='E')
            count++;
            else if (R2D2=='o'|| R2D2=='O')
            count++;
            else if (R2D2=='u'||R2D2=='U')
            count++;
            else if (R2D2=='y'||R2D2=='Y')
            count++;

    }
    System.out.println(count);
          }
           }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char` is not `String`. Declare `R2D2` as `char`

```
char R2D2 = '';
```

To check vowel make a method like below and reuse this method at `for` loop and `count` the vowel occurrence:

```
static boolean isVowel(char ch) {
    ch = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
    if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String lineOne,  R2D2 = "";
```

R2D2 is a string and you are comparing with a char             `if (R2D2== 'a'|| R2D2=='A')`

try this

for (int i = word -1; i>= 0; i--) 
        {
            R2D2= lineOne.charAt(i);

```
        if (R2D2=="a"|| R2D2=="A")
        count++;
        else if (R2D2=="e"||R2D2=="E")
        count++;
        else if (R2D2=="o"|| R2D2=="O")
        count++;
        else if (R2D2=="u"||R2D2=="U")
        count++;
        else if (R2D2=="y"||R2D2=="Y")
        count++;

}
```

One side not,you should compare using `.equals()` instead of `==`

Comment: Yes that was it thank you. I'm still new to java so this which I'm sure is obvious to some is not to me. Thanks again!

Comment: @user2872518  Actually `Masud`s answer is better. No unnecessary type conversions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix the long if chain you can do something like this:

```
if (anyOf(R2D2, "AaEeIiOoUuYy".toCharArray())
```

and later have:

```
private static boolean anyOf(char in, char[] items) {
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (in == items[i])
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If you want to be real fancy, then `Arrays.asList("AaEeIiOoUuYy".toCharArray()).contains(R2D2);`

Answer (score -2):

`R2D2` is of type String while the single quotes around a character (as in `'a'`) makes it a character literal. Strings cannot be assigned, or compared to a, character. That's the reason.

There are two kinds of problems in the code.

```
1. `R2D2= lineOne.charAt(i); // a character being assigned to a String variable`
```

Solution: `R2D2 = Character.toString(lineOne.charAt(i));`

```
2. `if (R2D2== 'a'|| R2D2=='A')` //strings being compared with char literals.
```

Solution:  `if (R2D2.equals("a")|| R2D2.equals("A"))`

FYI, To improved the maintenance you can also do.

```
if(R2D2.equalsIgnoreCase('a'))
```

Comment: [`charAt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) returns char and not String

Comment: Just realized that's another problem. But what I am saying, is that wrong? :)

Comment: The info is correct (sans `That's the reason.`) but it doesn't fix the problem.